# Center 3 div in parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to center 3 div into a parent div with no result.
Could you help me please ?

**HTML :**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#container {
   text-align: center;
}

#left, #middle, #right {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background: red;
    height: 90px;
}
```

**RESULT :**

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Change the `float:left;` to `display:inline-block;`, like this:

```
#left, #middle, #right {
    width: 200px;
    display:inline-block;
    background: red;
    height: 90px;
}
```

Comment: @wawanopoulos, it is because you have other styles, unknown for us.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this one:

```
#left, #middle, #right {
     width: 200px;
      display:inline-block;
      background: red;
      height: 90px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/c8Letqpc/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Try display flex. You'll need to add vendor prefixes!

```css
#container {
   text-align: center;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

#left, #middle, #right {
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    height: 90px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#container {
   text-align: center;
}

#left, #middle, #right {
    width: 200px;
    margin:0px auto;
    height: 90px;
}

#left
{
  background: red;
}

#middle
{
  background:blue;
}

#right
{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Bootstrap CSS and have a look at this example.

Here:

- COL=Column
- MD=Medium Sized Device
- 4 represents the partition of the screen as the Maximum column possible in a single row is 12

So 4/12=3 Panels in result.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">left</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">middle</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">right</div>
</div>
```

Try Bootstrap it will make your life easy.
Here's link for the Grip System you want [Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic).

Answer (score 0):

remove `float` & add display `inline-block`

```
#left, #middle, #right {
    width: 200px;
    display:inline-block;
    background: red;
    height: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-left: auto, margin-right:auto, width: 600px` to your container.

Thanks